# Display xml special character

Tags: c#

I am trying to display special characters present in xml. I have placed following conditions :

```
        if (text.Contains('<'))
        {
            text.Replace("<", "&lt;");
        }
        if (text.Contains('>'))
        {
            text.Replace(">", " &gt;");
        }
        if (text.Contains('&'))
        {
            text.Replace("&", " &amp;");
        }
        if (text.Contains('>'))
        {
            text.Replace("", "&quot;");
        }
```

But these escape the characters which is obvious.
Can someone tell how can I display these special characters.

Comment: What do you mean by display?  And for the nth time, can you please post a sample of the XML you're working with?

Comment: @Tim : I want to display them on powerpoint presentation which I am creating at runtime.

Comment: If your XML file contains `<` and `>` characters that mean your file is invalid. If you want to display a specific character you can perform a query with loops to check all the attributes (or open the file as a text file)

Comment: You need to stop working on XML as if it's just a string. Treating XML as strings leads to remarkably brittle "solutions". As Jon points out in his answer, there are plenty of good XML APIs available that do all of the hard work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need [**`SecurityElement.Escape`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape.aspx)

```
var result = SecurityElement.Escape(text);
```

Comment: There's no indication that the OP is doing anything with security. While this may do what's required, I don't think it's the cleanest way of doing it.

Answer (score 9):

Your *immediate* problem is that you're ignoring the result of `string.Replace` - strings are immutable in .NET, so you need:

```
result = result.Replace(...);
```

However, you'd be better off not trying to do this at all yourself - use an XML API instead. For example, if you want to create an XML document with an element containing a `<`, you can just use:

```
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("root", "<"));
Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

It will automatically be escaped on output, so you get:

```
<root>&lt;</root>
```

You should pretty much *never* do XML handling yourself - XML APIs are your friends, and LINQ to XML is a *very* good one.